# What does the unicode symbol U+2A69 mean in mathematics?

Tags: notation

I have not managed to find a definition for the "TRIPLE HORIZONTAL BAR WITH TRIPLE VERTICAL STROKE" (U+2A69) unicode character.

LE: I am curious why it would be labeled as a mathematical operator, since I have not seen it used anywhere.

Unicode specification: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a69/index.htm

Can somebody please explain if and how this symbol / operator is used in mathematics? Thank you.

Comment: I haven't seen this used before. Where have you seen this used?

Comment: I've never seen this before either. I tried it in [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), hoping that it would be a latex symbol, whose name I could search, but it returned no results. I think, despite Unicode categorising it as a "supplemental math operator", it probably isn't used in maths.

Comment: I doubt that this symbol has a generally accepted meaning. You have to look at your source to figure out how the author uses it. Many books have an index of symbols at the end (or sometimes beginning) of a book where you can see when a symbol was first used. And even if someone knew an answer to your question, this symbol is so rare that the next author probably uses it for a completely different purpose. Long story short: look it up at your text.

Comment: Without reference to some math text, it is hard to answer...

Comment: I haven't seen it used, hence the question. I am working on a Unicode inventory project and this particular symbol is one of the few hard ones nobody knows the meaning of. Since it's categorized under mathematical operators, I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: There is a good reason to keep a few symbols like that on hand, since mathematicians often end up with new notation, ad hoc or otherwise.

Comment: This symbol appeared in an xkcd comic months ago: https://xkcd.com/2606/. There are some discussions in https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2606:_Weird_Unicode_Math_Symbols#Discussion, but I don't think they have convincingly determined what the symbol means.

Comment: [TRIPLE HORIZONTAL BAR WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE' (U+2A68)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a68/index.htm) is (according to the comment) a combination of “equivalent” and “parallel to” which makes at least a little bit sense. The same comment can be found in the original [Unicode chart](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2A00.pdf) .  My *guess* is that someone defined this variant with three vertical strokes instead of two, without much thinking about its usefulness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a user of $\LaTeX$ for many years the correct symbol is `\equivVvert` from Table 104: stix Binary Relations. MathJax not see this symbol.  See pag. 59 of this paper: https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

[image]

Comment: That is interesting, but is the symbol actually *used* anywhere? And what it is *meaning?*

Comment: @MartinR Peraphs to indicate a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: I doubt that. Judging from the name, it should be some variant of an equivalence relation.

Comment: @MartinR Effectively.